# Data modification, set nested object to one level up and remove key

Tags: javascript, json, object

Need to flat or remove `platform` key from nested object like this, `platform` key will be same for every object

climb up nested object properties to one level up and remove key value(`platform`) to make data consistent, as platform key is different for nested objects

```
{
  option1: {
    platform : {
      key1:value1,
      key2:value2,
      key3:value3
    }
  },
  option2: {
    platform : {
      key1:value1,
      key2:value2,
      key3:value3
    }
  },
  option3: {
    platform : {
      key1:value1,
      key2:value2,
      key3:value3
    }
  }
}
```

Expected output is like

```
{
  option1: {
      key1:value1,
      key2:value2,
      key3:value3
  },
  option2: {
      key1:value1,
      key2:value2,
      key3:value3
  },
  option3: {
      key1:value1,
      key2:value2,
      key3:value3
  }
}
```

I tried approach using for loop and if condition, but that seems expensive operations. I need a more simpler way to do that.

Comment: Please add the code you've tried. Have you tried looping through the keys of the object? A simple loop like `for(const key in data) data[key] = data[key].platform` will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const obj = {"option1":{"platform":{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3"}},"option2":{"platform":{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3"}},"option3":{"platform":{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3"}}};
Object.keys(obj).forEach(k=>obj[k]=obj[k].platform);
console.log(obj);
```